# IIS7.5 session hanging on local development machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, windows-7, iis-7.5

**Summary**

Sessions within my **local** IIS7.5 stop responding for no obvious reason.

**Details**

I'm developing ASP.NET 2.0 web applications using Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit machine (which is a VMware instance running in VMware Workstation).

For no obvious reason, IIS just appears to stop working for the current session.  If I restart the browser, it works... for a short time, and then stops again.  If I open a different browser (while the first one is hanging) the new one works... for a short time.

Restarting IIS works (for a short time) or rebuilding the application (for a short time) - but there is absolutely no pattern to when it stops working... and it's driving me insane!!

There is no high-CPU-usage during this time, nor any high-memory-usage.

Nor does it not appear to be browser specific - I generally use FireFox for development, but this also happens on Chrome and IE.  Nor is it just on the machine, but also when I test the website on old browsers running in other virtual instances.

I'm not sure when this started happening, so I am unable to say what (if anything) had changed at the time.

Can anybody suggest any reason why this might be happening?

---

**UPDATE**

This is now driving me insane - so I've been doing more investigation.

Here is a screen-shot of FireBug which is showing that the actual `.aspx` request is completing correctly, but for some reason IIS is simply not responding to the request for all the files within the page.  The files are definitely there and have been served by IIS many, many times.

[image: FireBug showing the files which were requested, the ones in red being those which IIS failed to serve despite being there]

I have turned on the logs for IIS, and the only requests it has logged are those that show as successful in FireBug... those in red are missing.

```
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port c-ip sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2013-02-06 11:00:40 127.0.0.1 GET /default.aspx - 80 superuser 127.0.0.1 200 0 0 15
2013-02-06 11:00:40 127.0.0.1 GET /Org/Layout/Css/v0/FrontGeneral.css - 80 - 127.0.0.1 200 0 0 15
2013-02-06 11:00:40 127.0.0.1 GET /WebResource.axd d=IJ9YYVsWm9qkk8kUYcn2sYcQLbYErTn4We9MkwgF6JGUiPeoRWMmAKKsi_AbjNJQ-Je-l4D-1zuU66SBZi_kDHe1u7c1&t=634604425351482412 80 superuser 127.0.0.1 200 0 0 0
2013-02-06 11:00:40 127.0.0.1 GET /Scripts/v0/DefaultButtonFix.js - 80 - 127.0.0.1 304 0 0 0
```

I have also turned on the "Trace Failed Requests" (using information [from here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/tracing/tracefailedrequests)) but that is not producing anything... the directory is empty

Comment: try to attach a debugger, and check if you are not facing a deadlock, or infinite loop are any other possible error that may block the process.

Comment: Thanks @Steve - I'm confident it isn't an infinite loop (it's too random, and there is no CPU loading). However I'd not thought of dead-locks... although I'd expect some ASP.NET or SQL error should that be the case, not just a "IIS is not responding" type message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still testing this but have finally found success. Disabling my AVG virus scanner seems to clear this issue right up. If you have a virus scanner/security package dont bother adding exceptions, just blanket disable it temporarily and give it a go. You can add the exceptions back in if this test proves successful.

Know how you feel. This has been driving me nuts for weeks. I have been tweaking FF and Chrome settings with no effect whatsoever.

Best of luck...

Comment: BINGO!! You... are an absolute star. Why didn't I think of the AV before?! Thank you, thank you, thank you :-) (For anybody using AVG who experiences this, [here is the FAQ](http://www.avg.com/ww-en/faq.num-3857) to temporarily turn it off)